# Cannot find module ; Hyperledger Fabric Tutorial

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run a hyperledger tutorial app (fabcar).

I have followed the install and try to run `node query.js`.

I get this error on terminal:

```
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/pro/Documents/Code/HyperLegderFabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64/grpc_node.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pro/Documents/Code/HyperLegderFabric/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:30:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
```

I will appreciate pointers in debugging this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was I was running on python 3.6 .

I have intially used:

```
npm config set python python2.7

npm install --python=/usr/bin/python
```

and even

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm  -g --python=python2.7
```

but the problem was I this just `assumed` python 2.7 was on my pc, allowed me to install it.

When I ran the `node query.js` command, `grpc_node.node` was still a dependency that wasnt resolved.

To solve this, I had to

- Delete the fabric folder and download it again
- Create a python 2.7 virtual environment (`conda create --name py2_env numpy python=2.7` (I use the anaconda distro))
- Run `npm install`

Works fine now